# What do the "Read personal information" and "Write personal information" Active Directory permissions entail?

Tags: active-directory

I have a user account in an Active Directory domain. Despite this user account having the *Read personal information* and *Write personal information* permissions set, when logged in as this user, I cannot change their first name or surname.

What actual access do the permissions *Read personal information* and *Write personal information* entail? Is there any easy way to find out for any of the "general" permissions (i.e. any permission that isn't *Read/Write thisAndThat attribute*)?

The DC is a Windows 2012 machine and I'm accessing it using *Active Directory Users and Computers* (`dsa.msc`) from Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general (rather low-level) answer:

The property sets are stored under `CN=Extended-Rights,CN=Configuration,{domain}`; readable /writable property sets have the fifth (16, read) and/or sixth (32, write) bit set in the `validAccesses` attribute.

Any attribute (any object under `CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,{domain}` with `objectClass` set to `attributeSchema`) that is part of the property set has its `attributeSecurityGUID` attribute set to the property set's `rightsGuid` value. An attribute may apparently only be a member of up to one property set at a time.

Thanks to [Nathan C](https://serverfault.com/users/173547/nathan-c) for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: This is good info.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728117(v=ws.10).aspx) article, those permissions affect these attributes:

```
streetAddress

homePostalAddress

assistant

info

country/region name

facsimileTelephoneNumber (fax number)

International-ISDN-Number

Locality-Name

MSMQ-Digests

mSMQSignCertificates

Personal-Title

Phone-Fax-Other

Phone-Home-Other

Phone-Home-Primary

otherIpPhone

ipPhonenumber

primaryInternationalISDNNumber Phone-ISDN-Primary

Phone-Mobile-Other (otherMobile)

Phone-Mobile-Primary

Phone-Office-Other (otherTelephone)

Phone-Pager-Other

Phone-Pager-Primary

physicalDeliveryOfficeName

thumbnailPhoto (Picture)

postalCode

preferredDeliveryMethod

registeredAddress

State-Or-Province-Name

Street-Address

telephoneNumber

teletexTerminalIdentifier

telexNumber

primaryTelexNumber

userCert

User-Shared-Folder

User-Shared-Folder-Other

userSMIMECertificate

x121Address

X509-Cert
```

The user's name is not included in this list, so those aren't the proper permissions to grant. "General Information" is the category you'll find the name under.